# How do I delete an entry from an archived file?

Tags: c#, uwp

All I want to do is delete an item in a archived file. I can access the entry fine. Delete it, I cannot.

```cs
using (IArchive asharpArchive = ArchiveFactory.Open(zippedFilePath))
{
  int itemCounter = 0;

  foreach (var entry in asharpArchive.Entries.OrderBy(x => x.Key))
  {
    if (!entry.IsDirectory && itemCounter == selectedFile.CurrentItem)
    {
       entry.???; // No delete/remove option.
    }
    itemCounter++;
  }
}
```

I don't mind using something other than IArchive but it needs to work with all major archiving formats not just zip files.

Comment: First of all you have to decide on a list of formats which should be supported. Because for example, RAR archive doesn't support deleting without repack (correct me if I'm wrong). There is only one universal solution for it: unpack, delete some files and pack it back. But it could be time consuming, depends on an archive size.

Comment: I didn't realise RAR needed repacking. That must be why there is not a 'remove entry' option. Yeah, larger files may take some time. I think I may only support the action with zip files.

Comment: For Zip files only you can take a look on `System.IO.Compression` there is `ZipFile` class which will help you to get `ZipArchiveEntry`'s which has `Delete` method. More at [docs.MS.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

As Vitalii Ilchenko  pointed out. There is no simple solution to delete an entry from all major archive types. So I guess that's the answer?

For my case I will have a delete entry option in my application, however I will prompt users if they use RAR files etc. that the action is only supported with zip files.